How to assign virtual IP address from a router
My home network looks like this:

Everything is GNU/Linux and network-sharing is setup using networkmanager with nmtui, I have no experience with any other tools.
I need to access router A from PC like this:

And access PC-2 like this:

How can I do that? Which device should I modify? Which tools should I use? How to use it?
P.S. They're connected with ethernet ports and they don't have any spare port left so hardware connection is not possible.

so I can access them in local network Are you having problem accessing them with the 192.168.0.x IPs, or are you looking for ways to get traffics for some 10.20.0.x to be redirected to some 192.168.0.x, or both? (The latter is not a solution for the former, unless you are talking about getting rid of the 10.20.0.x subnet by bridging PC to 192.168.0.x.)
